# Overriding method constraints from lower level interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have an abstract class called `SynchronizeService` that is capable of writing data from a source to an `ISynchronizableDestinationService` destination. Here is its implementation:

```
public abstract class SynchronizeService<T> : ISynchronizeService<T> where T : ISynchronizable, new()
{
    protected ISynchronizableDestinationService _destination;

    public Type Type => typeof(T);

    public abstract Task<List<T>> GetSource();

    public async Task<List<T>> GetMissingFromDestination()
    {
        List<T> sourceList = await GetSource();
        List<T> destinationList = await _destination.Get<T>();

        return sourceList.Except(destinationList).ToList();
    }
    
    public async Task AddToDestination(List<T> data) => await _destination.Add(data);
}
```

The sources can vary depending on the type of `T`, so the `GetSource()` method is declared as abstract.

The `ISynchronizable` interface is empty and is used solely to ensure that only specific objects that implement this interface can be synchronized.

For the above code, the `ISynchronizableDestinationService` requires `Add` and `Get` methods. Here is the code for this interface:

```
public interface ISynchronizableDestinationService
{
    Task Add<T>(List<T> data) where T : ISynchronizable;
    Task<List<T>> Get<T>() where T : ISynchronizable;
}
```

The actual destination I'm trying to implement is `Notion`. I'm creating a `NotionService` that requires the entity to be synchronized to have a `DatabaseName` and a `Title`. Therefore, in addition to the `ISynchronizable` interface, I created an `INotionEntity` interface:

```
public interface INotionEntity : ISynchronizable
{
    public string DatabaseName { get; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

So, my Notion Entities should implement these interfaces to be compatible with my `NotionService`.

Now, I'm trying to create the `NotionService`, which should inherit from an interface on top of the `ISynchronizableDestinationService`:

```
public interface INotionService : ISynchronizableDestinationService
{
    new Task Add<T>(List<T> data) where T : INotionEntity, new();
    new Task<List<T>> Get<T>() where T : INotionEntity, new();
}
```

Essentially, I'm redefining the methods from `ISynchronizableDestinationService` with more specific constraints. I'm changing the constraints on `T` from `ISynchronizable` to `NotionEntity`, which implements the `ISynchronizable` interface. Therefore, my Notion Entities should work with the `ISynchronizableDestinationService`.

However, when implementing the `NotionService` as follows:

```
public class NotionService : INotionService
{
    //ctor and other stuff

    public async Task Add<T>(List<T> data) where T : INotionEntity, new()
    {
        //logic to add
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'NotionService.Add(List)' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'ISynchronizableDestinationService.Add(List)'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.

However, when I implement the explicit interface as suggested, it results in two methods: `INotionService.Add` and `ISynchronizableDestinationService.Add`. While this approach may seem somewhat inelegant, it could be acceptable if it worked correctly. The problem I face is that I cannot make `ISynchronizableDestinationService.Add` call `INotionService.Add` because the constraints on `T` are not the same.

Is there a way to override the method constraints from `ISynchronizableDestinationService` given that the newer constraints should be compatible with the old ones?

Comment: Not sure if this works, but why don't you put `T` constraints on the interface itself?

Comment: @PoulBak I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting, which interface are you talking about?

Comment: Both `ISynchronizableDestinationService` and `INotionService `.

Comment: The `ISynchronizableDestinationService` should not have any reference to `Notion` unfortunately

Comment: No, I mean `ISynchronizableDestinationService <T>` and `INotionService<T>` and with constraints on `T`.

Comment: Then  you don't have to redeclare the methods.

Comment: You are right, it worked ! Thank you ! Can you please create an answer so I mark it as solved please ?